# Trying to add a loop

Tags: java

I have a for loop, and I am trying to get it to add 5000 to the annual sales and print the calculations up to 10 times with the commission added, but I'm falling short. (This is of course after the original calculation) Why is my code falling short?   Also after my first output, I cant get the rest of the code to run.

```
System.out.println("Enter your annual sales");
String annual = input.nextLine();

int salary = 7550281;
int commission = 38_28;
if (Integer.parseInt(annual) < 92416_02) {
  commission = 37_28 * 1_32 / 100;
}
int compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * commission / 100 + salary;
System.out.println("compensation is: "+compensation );

for(int sales = (Integer.parseInt(annual) ); sales < 10; sales +=5000);
int salary = 7550281;
int commission = 38_28;
if (Integer.parseInt(annual) < 92416_02) {
  commission = 37_28 * 1_32 / 100;
}
int compensation = Integer.parseInt(annual) * commission / 100 + salary;

System.out.println("Your Annual compensation in 5000 increments are ");
```

Comment: All underscores should be decimal points.

Comment: for(int sales = (Integer.parseInt(annual) ); sales < 10; sales +=5000); why do you have a semi-colon after your for?  I think you mean to have a block of code in the for loop??

Comment: That is perhaps his bug.

Comment: "I'm falling short" isn't very specific. What isn't working?

Comment: @BrendanLong on my code the if (Integer.parseInt(annual) < 92416_02) { in the second set and System.out.println("Your Annual compensation in 5000 increments are "); are underlined.  also the annual in the last parseInt in underlined. so theres something wrong and my last outprint may be missing something

Comment: @PaulDraper when i try to turn them to decimals and put it as double i get a line underlined in red so i just leave them alone cause i dont know the issue

Comment: @user2934571 Try compiling the invalid code and see why the compiler doesn't like it.

Answer (score 3):

The correct `for` loop syntax is

```
for(int sales = (Integer.parseInt(annual) ); sales < 10; sales +=5000){
    //code
}
```

not

```
for(int sales = (Integer.parseInt(annual) ); sales < 10; sales +=5000);
```

though I think your logic needs some work. `sales` won't be less than 10 for more than one iteration of this loop, since you are adding 5000 to it each time.

Comment: `for(smth;smth;smth);` is correct Java syntax. Might not be what he wants but it *is* correct syntax.

Comment: it certainly is valid syntax, but it's not correct in this scenario.

Comment: then please clarify. Someone might think that Java does not allow this. Also if he wants to be adding to "sales" it is doable - he just needs to change it a bit (int declared outside the loop etc.). Not pretty but would work.

Answer (score 1):

Another shot in the dark, since you haven't given us your error message:

```
int commission = 38_28;
```

These `_`'s are ignored by the compiler. They're just [there to make numbers easier to read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html). For example, you could say:

```
int phoneNumber = 1_800_555_5555;
int socialSecurityNumber = 123_12_1234;
```

Which is identical to this, but potentially easier to read:

```
int phoneNumber = 18005555555;
int socialSecurityNumber = 123121234;
```

In your case, they're meaningless, so I would remove that.

Probably what you want is floating point numbers:

```
float commission = 38.28;
```

---

Also, this loop is extremely suspicious, besides ending with a semicolon:

```
for(int sales = (Integer.parseInt(annual) ); sales < 10; sales +=5000);
```

The fact that if `sales < 10`, you add *5000* is extremely strange. If that's what this loop is actually supposed to do, I'd write it as an `if` statement to be less confusing:

```
int sales = Integer.parseInt(annual);
if (sales < 10) {
    sales += 5000;
}
```

Or maybe `annual` starts out extremely negative?